# Specifically control IK behaviour

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

I tryed to rig the landing legs of a spaceship. So I can animate them retracting.
But when I try to retract them the IK bends the objects into the spaceship, instead of bending them up. Is there a way to "teach" the IKs to behave how I want them to?
Here you can see the IK picking torugh the leg the blue marking is how it should behave.
[image: IK setup pocking torugh the ship]
[image: Just the picking trough]
[image: The extended pose, showing the hinge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such easy IK chains (2 bones), it means that it is physically impossible. With given lengths, it shall behave like this.

So you should make the top part a little shorter / bottom part a bit longer.

Comment: Thank you yup I was dump dump